# Поиск индекса нужного словаря в списке

Tags: python

Делаю поиск по ютубу, получаю нужные данные в список из словарей. После мне нужно сравнить названия видео с запросом, чтобы получить только видео, содержащие именно этот запрос. Я сравниваю имя и получаю список совпадений. Теперь мне нужно как то найти индексы нужных словарей по ключам, которые в списке `a`. Как это сделать?

```
search_request = str('c major blues backing track')

youtube_search_results = [список, который ниже]

titles = []
for i in youtube_search_results[:]:
    a = i.get('title')
    titles.append(a)

a = []
for i in titles:
    if all(x in str(i).lower().split() for x in search_request.lower().split()) is True:
        a.append(i)
```

```
[{'title': 'Slow Blues Backing Track in C / Jam Tracks & Blues Guitar BackTracks TCDG', 'link': '/watch?v=axTQ3Tg9io8', 'id': 'axTQ3Tg9io8'}, {'title': 'C - Medium 12 Bar Blues Backing Track', 'link': '/watch?v=V6aZZFnZUVk', 'id': 'V6aZZFnZUVk'}, {'title': 'Slow Blues Jam | Sexy Guitar Backing Track (C)', 'link': '/watch?v=cVf1mkPvFHY', 'id': 'cVf1mkPvFHY'}, {'title': 'Chicago Style Blues Backing Track (C)', 'link': '/watch?v=3nM_MsXdm6E', 'id': '3nM_MsXdm6E'}, {'title': 'Chicago Blues Backing Jam Track (C)', 'link': '/watch?v=0fJ29wqHQyU', 'id': '0fJ29wqHQyU'}, {'title': 'Slow Blues Backing Track  in C', 'link': '/watch?v=P_uI_Eh6NXw', 'id': 'P_uI_Eh6NXw'}, {'title': 'Slow blues backing track in C major', 'link': '/watch?v=6e_9sqtSqpI', 'id': '6e_9sqtSqpI'}, {'title': 'Soulful Bluesy Groove | Guitar Backing Track Jam in C', 'link': '/watch?v=FjlE5dyiPlw', 'id': 'FjlE5dyiPlw'}, {'title': 'Slow Blues Jam Track in C Major', 'link': '/watch?v=q8IPOQa7VLI', 'id': 'q8IPOQa7VLI'}, {'title': 'Blues Backing Track in C [B.B. King style 4]', 'link': '/watch?v=tgMHbDh9dCw', 'id': 'tgMHbDh9dCw'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил тем же перебором.

```
links = []
for i in youtube_search_results:
    for j in a:
        if j in i['title']:
            links.append(i['link'])
```